# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 play nice with VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compatibility, sql-server-2008-r2

I know from firsthand experience that if you wanted to install both SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2008 on the same machine, you had to jump through all sorts of service packs and installation orders to ensure that both programs ran properly.

In my case, I have VS 2010 installed on my PC currently, and find I'm in need of the SQL Enterprise Manager, which is not included from the Visual Studio installation. What, if anything, do I need to do before installing SQL Server 2008 R2?

Related question: Does it matter which sub-version of SQL Server I install? (Thanks to my University connection, I have my pick between Developer, Enterprise, Standard, and Web; is one preferred in my case?)

Comment: it does not matter really ,but you should select the best for the project you are building , you should check the difference between each version & select the best for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "connect to DB" works well in VS2010 and 2008R8 works well enough with LINQ (as well as LINQ works, anyway). I would recommend using SQL Server Management Studio to actually deal with SQL Server though.

However, [BIDS **does not** work in VS2010](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&q=sql+server+bids&aq=0sx&aqi=g-sx4g-o1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=241062ed1d424d73). VS2008 is needed for it (or perhaps VS2005? I know not). I have VS2010 and VS2008 *both* installed for this reason.

The order of installation *does not matter* as long as none of the installations are "mysteriously corrupt" (of course VS2008 is a requirement for BIDS, but that's not a core part of SQL Server). Yes, you need to install the latest service packs for VS2008, but that should be done anyway. No "hoops". Just possibly an annoying SQL Server installation restart.

As far as sub-version: depends on what you need. MSDN should cover the differences in features fairly well. One thing to consider is avoiding a lock-in of more expensive version for features used (that aren't needed). It may or may not make a difference, depending upon target audience.

Comment: +1 for BIDS still needing VS2008. I forgot that and didn't install VS2008 before VS2010 on my last OS wipe, now I'm stuck having to remote to another pc when I need BIDS

Answer (score 0):

Install SQL Server before Visual Studio 2010, if for no reason other than avoiding accidentally installing SQL Server Express during the VS installer. I'd also recommend using the Developer edition of SQL Server since that's what it's designed for

Comment: Since I already have Visual Studio installed, are you suggesting that I uninstall it and start from scratch with SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I recently saw some post online where somebody ended up having a problem with VS2010 installed first, but I think it was a pretty unusual scenario. You'll probably be fine